# Solve PR merge conflict when merging feature into test from main

Tags: git

I've run into a problem where a Feature branch was created from the Main branch, and a conflict occurs when merging into the Test branch. How can I solve this conflict without merging the Test branch into the Feature branch (which will lead to the Test branch being merged into Main afterwards), or merging the Feature branch directly into the Test branch, ignoring the pull request?

Comment: Just stop and resolve the conflict at the moment where it occurs. So: "a conflict occurs when merging into the Test branch" — that's the moment, resolve the conflict now.

Comment: Actually, the PR page in Azure shows that the conflict exists, but there's no way in it to solve the conflict.

Comment: Azure was not mentioned in the question. But I'm pretty sure that there is always a way to do the resolution, no matter what hosting site you're using. You can certainly do it in GitHub.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could create an "integration", "conflict resolution", or "feature-test" branch. But note that this means you will have different code in your test branch (after merge) as compared to the code that ends up in your main branch.

```
git checkout -b feature-test feature
git merge test
# resolve conflicts
# commit conflict resolution (will contain changes from test _and_ feature)
# run your tests
# ...
# if everything successful, merge your original, still-unchanged feature branch
git checkout main
git merge feature
```

The commit with the conflict resolution will only exist on "feature-test".

You could also switch the order of how the branches are merged (test into feature vs. feature into test):

```
git checkout -b feature-test test
git merge feature
# optional: fast-forward test to include the conflict resolution: git push . HEAD:test
# resolve conflicts
# commit conflict resolution (will contain changes from test _and_ feature)
# run your tests
# ...
# if everything successful, merge your original, still-unchanged feature branch
git checkout main
git merge feature
```